# Load Flickity corousel with html5 videos "dynamically"

Tags: javascript, php, flickity

I'm building a flickity carousell with several html5 videos. When the carousel item turns in autoPlay or manual mode the next video should be loaded dynamically.

I would like to hear if there are already existing methods to create such a carousell and need some suggestions.